# Converting html cell into text area

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to convert the HTML DOM table into text area. For example I have a table generated on the page with data.When the user clicks the edit button the individual cells should convert into text area so that it can be edited.For example my code

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "data";
    cell2.innerHTML = "data";
    cell3.innerHTML = "data";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact issue here? Questions usually have a "`?`" somewhere

Comment: I guess you should create a textarea element, put the textContent of the cell into it, then replace the content of the cell with the textarea.

Comment: Where is the 'edit button'? Where's your HTML? What have you tried to do, and what went wrong?

Comment: Hey Roko C. Buljan I suggest you read the question a couple of times before posting an idiotic comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

### Solution 1; clicking on a cell enables edit

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var target = e.target;
    //test if clicked element is TD.
    if (target && target.tagName && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td")
    {
        //make cell editable
        target.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        //on blur close the editable field and return to normal cell.
        target.onblur = function(){this.removeAttribute('contenteditable');}
    }

});
```

### Solution 2; clicking on edit enables edit all cells

```
var editBtn = document.getElementById("editbutton") //this is pseudo, change it to reflect your own button
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

editBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var tdList = table.querySelectorAll("td"); //select all td elements

    for (var i = 0; i < tdList.length; ++i)
    {
         //iterate over all cells and set contentEditable to true, allows user input.
         tdList[i].setAttribute("contentEditable", true);

         //if you want textArea you can do this (it's commented out)
         //Choose one of these methods, or the contentEditable or textarea
         /*
         var tempNode = document.createElement("textArea");
         tempNode.style.height = "100%";
         tempNode.style.width = "100%";
         tempNode.style.border= "0px solid transparent";
         tempNode.value = tdList[0].textContent;
         tdList[i].innerHTML = "";//wipe content of td
         tdList[i].appendChild(tempNode);
         */
    }

});
```

Off course the save button can use the same loop to iterate over all the TD. You can access the value of the td/textarea with the following

```
tdList[i].textContent; //contentEditable
tdList[i].children[0].value; //textarea.
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Made some changes, however it is, referring to your comment above, difficult to answer the question of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the similar behavior in my earlier project using contenteditable DOM element. Instead of converting a table cell into a text area when user clicks on it, you can toggle the contenteditable attribute of that element in the following way

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var target = e.target;
    //test if clicked element is TD.
    if (target && target.tagName && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "td")
    {
        //make cell editable
        target.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        //on blur close the editable field and return to normal cell.
        target.onblur = function(){this.removeAttribute('contenteditable');}
    }

});
```

Here I have assumed that each of your table cell has a `<div>` inside. You can appropriately style it using CSS so that it looks like a textarea. Again when user clicks outside any cell, you need to remove the contenteditable property of the previously selected cell to make it look like a regular cell again. Hope it helps!

Comment: Does this even work? `getElementsByTagName` returns an `node list` and the `addEventListener` isn't in it's prototype by my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple making your table `contenteditable`

```js
var editBtn = document.querySelectorAll("button[class^=edit-]");

function editTable(){
  var id = "table-"+this.className.match(/\d+/);
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var ed = table.iseditable^=1;
  table[ed?"setAttribute":"removeAttribute"]("contenteditable", true);
  this.textContent = ed ? "SAVE" : "EDIT"
}

for(var i=0; i<editBtn.length; i++){
  editBtn[i].addEventListener("click", editTable, false);
}
```

```css
table td{
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:#eee;
}
table[contenteditable]{
  outline: 2px dashed #ad8;
}
```

```html
  <table id="table-1">
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
  </table>
  
  <button class="edit-1">EDIT</button>
  
  
  <table id="table-2">
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td></tr>
  </table>
  
  <button class="edit-2">EDIT</button>
```

The buttons have a **numbered class**. To retrieve the referenced table ID, inside the `editTable()` function retrieve the number and create the ID out of the *class* using:

```
var id = "table-"+this.className.match(/\d+/);
```

than toggle a HTMLElement property using `^=1` which will do (`1,0,1,0,....`), and used as boolean you can than toggle whatever you need. Attributes, textContent etc.